# Can I use an HM10 connected to a Raspberry Pi Pico to read from a BLE notification?

Tags: bluetooth, pi-pico

I have a Raspberry Pi Pico and would like to read BLE notify data from an external sensor should using an HM10. I've seen the [HM-10](https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/PIC32/uart/HM10/DSD%20TECH%20HM-10%20datasheet.pdf) datasheet and don't see anything there that would be of help. Is it possible?

I tried connecting using `AT+CONF` and `AT+CHAR` but that doesn't work (I think that's because the latter works only in peripheral mode). Is there something that can be done?

I also tried using [this help page](https://www.thinker-talk.com/post/bluecard-part-5-arduino-nano-bluetooth-module-how-to-at-09-or-hm-10) but my HM-10 doesn't support "AT+HELP\r\n", "AT HELP\r\n" or "AT+INQ" (I don't get any data back from my HM-10), but the commands on the datasheet do work, so it's not a baud speed problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but I would like to try to help (making many assumptions along the way).

So, a great first step would be to figure out what firmware you're running. The easiest way you may be able to do this is via the **nRF Connect** phone application.

1. Within the app, you should see your HM-10 device named HMSoft, or whatever name you gave it if this has been changed.
2. If you can find your device when it's powered on (Should have a slow blinking red LED at least on my HM-10), connect to it and look for the last Unknown Service (Should be 0xFFE0) and click to expand its Characteristics.

   - By default, there should be one Unknown Characteristic shown, 0xFFE1.
3. Now you're gonna want to click the up arrow next to the only characteristic, change the type to TEXT instead of BYTE..
4. Enter in the text box to the left of TEXT (previously BYTE..): `AT+VERR?`
5. Look for text that says `"HMSoft V605"` or something similar

Now you know which firmware your HM-10 uses. If you want to use commands specific to its version, go to [Huamao's website](http://www.jnhuamao.cn/download_rom_en.asp?id=83), or download the latest firmware from Wayback Machine's snapshot for the v710 HM10 firmware file. Then you'll need to do some soldering onto your HM10 to allow for flashing new firmware onto your HM10 by following [this guide](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/how-to-flash-the-firmware-on-cloned-hm-10-ble-module-using-arduino-uno). There is also a different guide given by Huamao himself, which you can find on his website.

**If you don't want to go the route of flashing new firmware, you could change the UUID of the characteristic to signify a given value taken from your sensor by reading the sensor, converting it to the 4 byte number range, then using AT+CHAR (Or potentially AT+UUID instead) to signify your sensor's value.**

I hope this gives you a better idea of the HM10's capability. It all really depends on the firmware version your HM10 is running.